# Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [executor]

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I'm trying to learn Spring MVC 2.0 and Spring Web Flow 1.0.

I get following error (possibly when the dispatcher delegates a request to flow):

> Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [executor]

I am using the Spring 2.0 and Web Flow 1.0 jar files in the application's build path.

Below is my Spring MVC 2.0 configuration file:

```
<bean name="/phonebook.htm" 
      class="org.springframework.webflow.executor.mvc.FlowController">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/> 
</bean> 
<!-- Resolves flow view names to .jsp templates --> 
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/> <property name="suffix" value=".jsp">
</bean>
```

And my Spring Web Flow 1.0 config:

```
<flow:executor id="flowExecutor" registry-ref="flowRegistry"/> 
<!-- Creates the registry of flow definitions for this application --> 
<flow:registry id="flowRegistry"> <flow:location path="/WEB-INF/flows/**-flow.xml"/>
</flow:registry>
```

Comment: Firstly, we'll need more information than like, like seeing your configuration. Also, Both Spring 2.0 and Webflow 1.0 are *very* old. If you're just starting out with this stuff, then you should use the recent versions.

Comment: Spring 2.0 configuration file..
<bean name="/phonebook.htm" class="org.springframework.webflow.executor.mvc.FlowController">
  <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/>
 </bean>

 <!-- Resolves flow view names to .jsp templates -->
 <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
 </bean>

Comment: Spring webflow 1.0 configuration file.
<flow:executor id="flowExecutor" registry-ref="flowRegistry"/>
 
 <!-- Creates the registry of flow definitions for this application -->
 <flow:registry id="flowRegistry">
  <flow:location path="/WEB-INF/flows/**-flow.xml"/>
 </flow:registry>

Answer (score 1):

When eclipse deploy web application to tomcat it also deploy those jar files to lib directory which was not in build path.. so now when tomcat goes to execute.. it would probably find two jar files for web flow i.e. webflow 1.0 and webflow 2.0 And giving me the error.. i.e. when two different version jar files for webflow are in lib director.

i would also like to thank skaffman for his support..

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it looks like the problem is with the `<flow:executor>` element in your webflow config. Spring is complaining that it doesn't understand what that means, and it's probably because you're missing the namespace declaration in the config file. This looks something like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-1.0.xsd">
```

Your root element must look something like that. See documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/1.0.x/reference/flow-executor.html#executor-jsf-simple-webflow-setup).

Comment: Actually i was unable to post this namespace so i had posted only inner configuration part.
Actually i do have same namespace in place..but it didn't work...

Comment: @Yogi: The error message suggests otherwise, you've probably got something not quite right in there. Please edit your question and paste the whole contents of both config files.